# Can you use Pre-Build Event Command Lines to set up references for an alias used within your application?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I have been asked to import an dll into my project, and another version of the .dll already exists. In my code I have added the following lines to set up an alias for the .dll.

```
extern alias somealias;

using System
... shortened for brevity
```

What I do know is that you need to use `csc.exe` to set up a compiler command to show which assembly this alias will reference to

```
csc /r somealias=.\Lib\Version2\MyDll.dll .\MyFolder\MyClass.cs
```

I have never worked with Pre-build event command lines before, and I know that the project properties contains a tab where you can set up Pre-build command lines. I was just wondering if you can somehow, instead of using the `csc.exe` compiler, can you use the Pre-Build Event Command Line Box for this instead? I have tried running my command, but got `error 9009`

[image: Build Events Pre-build event command line]

**My Question is (if this explanation was too riddling), can I use the Pre-build event command line to set up references for aliases? Is there an easier way for me to use the .dll without having to delete any of them? (the simple names for these .dlls are the same.)**

**Read Material:**

•[Extern Alias](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ansonh/archive/2006/09/27/774692.aspx)

Comment: cant you change the dll name?

Comment: Simple name of the dlls are the same. so even if I change the dll name, I will still have trouble referencing both of them

Comment: Error 47 An assembly with the same simple name 'myDll, Version=0.0.0.9065, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null has already been imported. Try removing one of the references or sign them to enable side-by-side. E:\...\myDll.dll Admin.MyMobileSuite.com.

The two "Similar" Dlls are actually different versions containing different code, both very important in our application